# C++ height & width of rectangle between 3 to 20 with program checks for illegal entries

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program that allows a user to select height and width of the rectangle (between 3 and 20) with any given character. I need to put in illegal entries that allows used to keeping trying inputs if its out of range.  This program below works, but only with the condition of either less than 3 or greater than 20. How can I get this program to work using both conditions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int height, width;
    char ch;

    do {
        cout<<"Enter desired height (3 to 20): ";
        cin>>height;
        if (height>3)
            cout<<"";
        else if (height<3)
            cout<<"Illegal entry."<<endl;

    } while (height<3);

    do {
        cout<<"Enter desired width (3 to 20): ";
        cin>>width;
        if (width>3)
            cout<<"";
        else if (width<3)
            cout<<"Illegal entry. "<<endl;
    } while (width<3);

    cout<<"What character would you like for your rectangle? ";
    cin>>ch;


    for (int i=0; i<height; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<width; j++) {
            cout<<ch;
        }
        cout<<endl;

        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am getting bored of typing in "indent your code". Also always use braces - you do not wish to be caught with your trousers around you ankles.

Comment: I only indented what I needed to get it to post. The indenting is proper in my program.

Comment: You just need an AND clause. "if height > 3 *and* height < 20, then...". Look it up under *logical operators*. Oh, and actually you want >=, not >; 3 is a legal value, and you need to accept it as valid.

Comment: I tried putting in while (width>=3 && width<=20) *same for height* but it doesn't function properly.

Comment: Another thing, unrelated to your question but related to @EdHeal's comment: due to wrong bracings, you return 0 inside the rectangle drawing, and you'll never get more than one row.

Comment: @Iserni The bad brace might have been my edit; it was missing a brace at the end, and maybe I added it in the wrong place. Yeah, the brace should have been added above to the for block.

Comment: Figured it out, thank you everyone!! much appreciated.

Comment: @user3479110 - Make indentation your second nature

Answer (score 0):

*How can I get this program to work using both conditions?*

You want to use logical and `&&` and logical or `||`

```
if ( (height>3) && (height < 20) )
    cout << "";
else if (height<3 || height > 20)
    cout << "Illegal entry." << endl;
```

Comment: thank you. I was using && statements for both conditions rather than || . As soon as I changed it the program worked great. Thank you!!